# Saving `Date` to `CoreData` does not work

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uitextfield, nsdate

I am trying to save a Date into a textfield and have that save into CoreData.  I have the textfield set up and am able to use the date picker just fine with the NSDateFormatter but I am having trouble with getting it to save into the textfield into CoreData.

Comment: 1. idea: pass an error to save and look at what it says

Comment: 2. idea: do you know it is saving that fails? maybe reading fails

Comment: I get the following errors                                                                                 1. textFieldDDate.NSDate = date (UITextField does not have a member named NSDate)  2.  newItem.ddate = textFieldDDate.text (Cannot assign a value type String to a value of type NSDate)                                                              I know I am missing something to clear them but can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension NSDate{
    var stringValue: String{
        return self.toString()
    }

    func toString() -> String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let str = formatter.stringFromDate(self)
        return str
    }
}

extension String{
        var dateValue: NSDate?{
            return self.toDate()
        }

        func toDate() -> NSDate? {
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            if let date = formatter.dateFromString(self) {
                return date
            }else{
                // if format failed, Put some code here
                return nil // an example
            }
        }
    }
```

add this befor your class or another swift file,
then change `textFieldDDate.NSDate = ddate` to:

```
textFieldDDate.text = ddate.stringValue
```

you can only use text(String!) with UITextField,also only NSDate in your newItem.ddate.

change `newItem.ddate = textFieldDDate.text` to

```
newItem.ddate = textFieldDDate.text.dateValue
```

Comment: Ok, that fixed one problem but i still have one more.  newItem.ddate = textFieldDDate.text.  Cannot not assign a value type String to a value of type NSDate.

Comment: i edit the answer, add some lines for fix that.you can only give a correct value type. String to String, NSDate to NSDate, if not the same, you need change it

Comment: OK, that worked but now in my table view I have another problem, just added it to "Answer you own question

Answer (score 1):

I see `var ddate = data.valueForKey("ddate")`, I guess it is type of NSDate? maybe you need change it to String, it can't be just use `as!(?) String`,if I am right, you need use my code of **extension NSDate{}** to change it too.

Comment: Yes, date is of type NSDate.  Just not sure where to change it

Comment: before  ` cell.detailTextLabel!.text = " \(ddate) location: \(diveloc)"`

Comment: oh crap, app is crashing while saving date.

Comment: debug it step by step.  the type of date in coreDate and in your viewController,maybe not the same.

Comment: CoreData is ddate as Date as well as the AddDiveLogViewController

Comment: Add a new Answer for this

Answer (score 1):

I checked your codes, just find some lines maybe it is save data to coreData:

```
 if segue.identifier == "update" {

        var selectedItem: NSManagedObject = myDivelog[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row] as! NSManagedObject

        let ADLVC: AddDiveLogViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddDiveLogViewController

        ADLVC.divenumber = selectedItem.valueForKey("divenumber") as! String
        ADLVC.ddate = selectedItem.valueForKey("ddate") as! NSDate
        ADLVC.divelocation = selectedItem.valueForKey("divelocation") as! String
        ADLVC.existingItem = selectedItem

        }
```

am I right? I get this link of an answer of how to save a Data to CoreData for you. because maybe something wrong in there.

here it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/26025022/5113355

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean

Comment: Well it was working fine before the changes made to the NSDate

Comment: hmmm, I need more code for your project.  I can't debug it

Comment: You can download the project from here.  I do appreciate all the help https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hwrgvzvdfqrucn/LogMyDiveIn.zip?dl=0

Comment: Sorrry! I'm get it just now. I have do some fix with your datePickerView.some problem in there, the textfield can't get String Value of DatePicker in your code.

Comment: OK, that worked to save the data, Thanks. But when I select the tableView it crashes.  Any ideas?

Comment: change `existingItem.setValue(textFieldDDate.text as String, forKey: "ddate")` to `existingItem.setValue(textFieldDDate.text.dateValue!, forKey: "ddate")` ,because ddate is NSDate

Comment: Sorry, it still crashes

Comment: I'm fix it ,here it is [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2v3pddqd9v0u6m/LogMyDiveIn.zip?dl=0),Just test for add and save, selected row then edit something,save again.no crash

Comment: Sorry but it still keeps crashing

Comment: Screenshot is here, https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvu2a7cr3llyulm/2015-07-21_06-57-40.jpg?dl=0