# Swift , CoreData not inserting a record

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a function which errors where marker // ERRORS HERE

The db is empty, I try to append a Persistence record, then set its values,

`tasks[0].persistencevalue = "Some Text"`!

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

The stack shows :

> 2017-08-18 10:09:07.158047+0100 Ontrack[6491:1684506] [error] error: 
>   CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on
>   NSManagedObject class 'Persistence'
>       CoreData: error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class "Persistence" 2017-08-18 10:09:08.678 Ontrack[6491:1684506] -[Persistence   setPersistencevalue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x60800026a040
>       2017-08-18 10:09:08.681 Ontrack[6491:1684506] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[Persistence setPersistencevalue:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x60800026a040'

```
func Update() {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let app = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate )        

    var tasks: [ Persistence] = []    

    let pers = Persistence()

    tasks.append(pers)
    cnt = tasks.count
    // ERRORS HERE 
    tasks[0].persistencevalue = Rate.text!
    // END ERROR
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CoreData Swift: How to save and load data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586593/coredata-swift-how-to-save-and-load-data)

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33307824/3985749) to the "Failed to Call Designated initializer" error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I was able to fix the problem with the following code.  Hope it helps someone with the same problem.

```
func Update() {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let app = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate )

    var persistencies: [ Persistence]?


    var cnt = persistencies?.count

    var perRec: AnyObject! = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Persistence", into: context) as NSManagedObject

    perRec.setValue(DbKeys.PERSISTENCE_SPEECHRATE_KEY, forKey: "persistencekey")
    perRec.setValue(Rate.text, forKey: "persistencevalue")

    do {
     try context.save()
    } catch {
        print (" ERROR")
    }

    app.saveContext()

    do {
        persistencies = try context.fetch(Persistence.fetchRequest())
    } catch {
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }


    cnt = persistencies?.count

  }
```