# Swift: UICollectionViewCell get data only once

Tags: ios, swift

I have a horizontal scrolling `UICollectionView` with each `collectionViewCell` containing a `tableView` displaying a feed of `post` objects. I would like to fetch data only once for each `collectionViewCell`.

My current implementation fetches data whenever the `collectionViewCell` is being dequeued, ie when the user swipes left and right on the `collectionView`, the cell sometimes reloads and fetches data, interrupting the user experience.

Code so far:

```
//At ViewController
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
    cell.topic = topics[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

//At FeedCell, the custom collectionViewCell
class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tv.delegate = self
        tv.dataSource = self
        //Setup tableView work
        return tv
    }()

    var topic: Topic? {
        didSet {
             if let _ = topic {
                 getData()
             }
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //Setup views work
    }
```

Here are some of my other attempts:

**Attempt 1**, move `getData()` to `init(frame: CGRect)`, but `getData` doesn't get called as `topic` isn't set yet.

**Attempt 2**, move `getData()` to `layoutSubviews()` like so:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    if let _ = topic {
        getData()
    }

    super.layoutSubviews()

}
```

But this recursively calls `getData()`.

**UPDATE:**
Code for `getData()`

```
var posts = [Post]()
fileprivate func getData() {
    getDataFromApi { (posts, err) in
        if let err = err {
           print(err)
        }

        if let posts = posts {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if posts.count != 0 {
                    self.posts += posts
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the lazy keyword for the tableView. Why would you want that? That might very well be the reason why the UX is not smooth. Also, please share the getData() method. Where are you setting your tableView delegate and dataSource?

Comment: @rs7 i set tableView delegate and dataSource inside the tableView itself. See edits. The `getData()` simply fetches data from API and then populate a separate `post` array. `tableView` then access this `post` array to display each row. But I suppose the `tableView` isn't the issue since `tableView` isn't the one calling `getData()`?

Comment: I would call getData() in a background thread (.userInitiated). This should help make the experience smoother for your user. As an option you can show an activity indicator until the data loads. My other question is: what type of data are you downloading in getDataFromApi? Is it just text? NSCaching would be a good option to avoid having to download the data every time your user scrolls through the collectionView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for performance on all app opens it would be best to cache this data to the device with CoreData after it is loaded for the first time  (or something like the local datastore on Parse Server or Firebase)

Queries would look something like this

--> Check CoreData for objects you need

--> If found objects display in tableview on collection cell pretty much instantly

--> If no objects load from database to display on tableview

--> Save loaded data to CoreData for next time

[CoreData Swift: How to save and load data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586593/coredata-swift-how-to-save-and-load-data)

If you are looking for improved performance on just each time you visit the view controller I would store the data into a nested array on the vc as it is loaded

```
var tablesData = [[Object]]()
```

On the way forward you could set them like this after each cell load

```
tablesData[collectioncellindex] = tableobjects
```

You can then access each object like this on the way back on each tableView on the collection cell

```
let tableobject = tablesData[collectioncellindex][tableviewrow]
```

Think of the first index as the collection cell (with all the table data) and the second index as the tableview cell (with the data for one tableview cell)

You could also even load all the data into the nested array initially so that it wouldn't have to load in between swipes - I suppose it depends how much data you need to load and what kind but if it doesn't take too long that might be your better option

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have explored using persistence before but its not optimal. The `collectionView` is dynamically generated, meaning to say each `collectionViewCell`s topic is different for each user. User may not access all cell so storing all data in persistence isn't optimal. Besides, it would also encounter same issue, that fetching data will consistently be triggered when I load the collectionviewcell

Answer (score 0):

Call getData() on a background thread as to not block the main thread while your data is downloading. .userInteractive and .userInitiated are both high priority background threads. If you expect the download to be short and quick use the first one, otherwise use the latter.

```
var topic: Topic? {
    didSet {
         if let _ = topic {
             DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated) {
                 self.getData()
             }
         }
    }
}
```

You can polish the user experience by adding an activityIndicator and also play with caching if needed. Caching helps you persist data temporarily so that you don't have to re-download it when the user needs to access it again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I do have an activityIndicator showing already. But its always showing up randomly when I swipe between cells (I suppose its because the cells are being dequeued). The thing with caching is that I will still need to refresh data, and the method of calling data would still be similar, that the cells will dequeue and call getData() when I swipe between cells. I only wanna fetch data when the user swiped to that cell, and fetch only once.

Comment: Did you move your getData() to a background thread? Also, what kind of data are you displaying? (plain text, images?) Caching stores the data temporarily so you don't have to re-download it and you are only caching what you are displaying.